# How to search in many servers their logs and sort the information?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, logging

The idea is very simple:

I would like to pass some word as `something` as argument to some script, then this scripts d would search in all my servers into their logs, when found something relevant, they would throw this information in some file which this one would be `rsync` to some server which would sort the whole information of all servers and presents to me where and when `something` has been passed.

I think this is possible because my servers are syncronized with `NTP` which grants me they won't have the exact same time in two or more servers.
But I wonder if this is a good idea and how do this search and sort these logs ?

The problem for me is:

1) How do I access my servers to run this search in each one of them ?

2) How do I make this search ?

3) How do I sort this whole information in the `final` log (contained the whole information of all servers) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add your ssh keys to each server and then from your main server add this to your bashrc

```
export web_servers=(server1 server2 server3 server4 )
function grepallservers() {

      for s in ${web_servers[@]}; do echo $s; ssh $s grep "$@"; done

}

function all-serv-grep() {

        grepallservers $1 /var/log/error.log
}
```

Comment: Or, don't add your ssh keys and just type your password for every server.

Comment: what I understand of your code is: the for would pass in all servers (server1, server2...) then it would do an ssh, but the `grep "$@` thing I didn't understand very well.
And what `grepallservers $1 /var/log/error.log` do ? I takes an argument the and throw the info in `/var/log/error.log` ?

Comment: IP addresses would pass for servers (0.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2)
the `all-serv-grep` function would `grep` for a string in  each servers `/var/log/error.log` file